# Regex: make 'zero or one time occurence' condition but only for the last match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have this string:

```
key1:val1;key2:val2;key3:val3
```

It could be written like this too:

```
key1:val1;key2:val2;key3:val3;
```

I want to preg_match_all both of strings above so it will return same array like this:

MATCHES 1

```
Array
(
    [0] => key1
    [1] => key2
    [2] => key3
)
```

MATCHES 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => val1
    [1] => val2
    [2] => val3
)
```

Right now, I'm using this regex:

```
(.*?):(.*?);
```

Unfortunately, it don't work for the first string. I tried using regex below before, but the result was worse:

```
(.*?):(.*?);?
```

Here is my experiment so far: https://3v4l.org/5HAco
. If there is a pure PHP function to solve this problem, I can accept it too.

Comment: Is [that](https://regex101.com/r/8jZpcr/1) what you want?

Comment: @Toto Yeah thank you, can you post your answer so I can pick it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "key1:val1;key2:val2;key3:val3";

preg_match_all("/(.*?):(.*?)(?:;|$)/",$text,$matches);
print_r($matches);


$text = "key1:val1;key2:val2;key3:val3;";

preg_match_all("/(.*?):(.*?)(?:;|$)/",$text,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => key1:val1;
            [1] => key2:val2;
            [2] => key3:val3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => key1
            [1] => key2
            [2] => key3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => val1
            [1] => val2
            [2] => val3
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => key1:val1;
            [1] => key2:val2;
            [2] => key3:val3;
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => key1
            [1] => key2
            [2] => key3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => val1
            [1] => val2
            [2] => val3
        )

)
```